# JavaScript: Pushing a list to a new list with repeating values in original using a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a list List = [Boy, Boy, Boy, Girl, Boy, Key, Girl] how do I grab only the each of these values and push it on to another new array in JavaScript using a for loop?

Input = [Boy, Boy, Boy, Girl, Boy, Key, Girl]
Output = [Boy, Girl, Key]

Comment: I can't find a problem that is similar to this one on here. Don't know why it's a duplicate. can you send a link? thanks

Comment: You basically want to remove dupe elements from an array. In the link above there are dozens of methods how to solve it, including for loop. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229784/6695924